# Using Spark Streaming without downloading spark Apache

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

i have some tweets data and i want to analyze it using Spark Streaming. 
Can I use spark Streaming without Downloading Spark Apache or even using the Spark-like environment?

---

Comment: Why would you want to use Spark without downloading it...?

Comment: I'd say it's possible in a way... so you might set up a mvn / sbt projects, specify there spark dependency and then just develop simple main method, which will use local[N] spark context. This way you don't need to download anything (mvn / sbt will do) nor configure it anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can.

Spark Streaming relies on the underlying Spark framework for its API and features like distributed computing and fault tolerance.